# Menu button in XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

Is there any type of menu button in windows phone 7 XNA? I want to create a menu buttons for my game like CCMEnu in Cocos2D?
This is my GamePage.xaml.cs.

```
public GamePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        newButton = new Button();
        newButton.Height = 75;
        newButton.Width = 250;
        ///newButton.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        newButton.Content = "Dynamically added";


        // Get the content manager from the application
        contentManager = (Application.Current as App).Content;
        contentManager.RootDirectory = "Content";

        // Create a timer for this page
        timer = new GameTimer();
        timer.UpdateInterval = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);
        timer.Update += OnUpdate;
        timer.Draw += OnDraw;

        newButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(newButton_Click);
    }

  void setUpBackgroundAndTitle()
    {
        // Draw a background picture with scaling since the picture is large //
        spriteBatch.Draw(background, new Vector2(0, 0), null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(0.9f, 0.9f), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        spriteBatch.Draw(rhymeImage, new Vector2(400, 0), null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(1f, 1f), SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
        spriteBatch.Draw(gameImage, new Vector2(180, 0), null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(1f, 1f), SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
        spriteBatch.Draw(titleImage, new Vector2(150, -70), null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(1f, 1f), SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(newButton);
    }
```

The xaml file.

```
<Button Content="Button" Height="71" Name="button1" Width="160" Click="button1_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the Silverlight + XNA recipe instead of going only with XNA?

That way you can just use all the controls Silverlight has (like the Button!) instead of having to draw them from scratch in XNA!

Check the "Silverlight/XNA Framework Sample" sample in the [Windows Phone Code Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Comment: OK when I did that the button is going below the background. How to bring it to front. OR How can I dynamically create a button.

Comment: Just a guess, but that is probably related to the order of the methods in the OnDraw method... the Silverlight element rendering should be the last one on the method (in order to stay on top)

Comment: I am placing this button in the xml. then how to bring it to top.

Comment: Edit the question and add some of the XAML code + c# code you're using... that way will be easier to help you!